# The sum of palindromes from 100 to 900

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm working with palindromes from $100-999$. I'm having trouble with the step highlighted in red. Can someone explain the algebra to me?
[image]

Taken from: Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics: An Applied Introduction, by Ralph P. Grimaldi, 5th edition.

Comment: Do you mean why $aba \equiv 100a + 10b + a = 101a + 10b$ ? Or how to get to the next line?

Comment: The aim seems to be to practice summation, there are easier approaches.

Comment: @Winther I was wondering how to get to that step. Thanks for the help.

Comment: btw $aba$ is probably not the best notation to use as it looks very similar to $a\cdot b \cdot a$ and some students might be confused by this. $[a,b,a]$ is perhaps a better notation to avoid this.

Comment: I agree. I'll be sure to pass a line on to the textbook writer.

Comment: So the question is answered? Correct? You don't need help with the summations?